# 32 Bit GCC Compiler storage and manipulation of char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, 32-bit

Background: Am new to 32 bit compilers and creating routines to manipulate char arrays for an embedded system using a newly adopted target: the SiLabs Leopard Gecko processor using the GCC 32 bit compiler.

The issue: memory on our embedded system is limited and I am trying to understand how the compiler stores char arrays so that we efficiently use the RAM and Flash available. The compiler reports RAM usage that increments in 4 byte increments which fits with a default 32 bit word size ( i.e. char X[1] to char X[4] all result in RAM allocation of 4 bytes, char[5] results in an allocation report of 8 bytes).

From what I understand, the compiler will store all variables as 32 bit values (excepting for long's and such)

The Question: does the above memory report imply that the compiler creates the necessary assembly code to pack a char[4] into a single 32 bit word AND handle the byte parsing if I were to write a line such as char Y = char Array[2]  ?

Comment: The compiler will conform to the C language standard if it is a C compiler.

Comment: The architecture which I work with state in its EABI that the stack should be allocated in 8 bytes. So if I would create a 9 byte char array that would cause 16 bytes to be allocated. Similar thing going on with this architecture I assume. I dont think this arhitecture doing this packing thing you described simply issuing a Load Byte command if it has one.

Comment: @Eraklon no it is not correct. Stack has to be aligned only during the excepption handling. It can be done by the hardware or left for the programmer. It is not EABI - it is hardware. But it is not relevant here.

Comment: @EOF OP asks about gcc not the C compiler.

Comment: @P__J__ I hate to break it to you, but gcc *is* a C compiler (among other languages).

Comment: @EOF - fanatics say **NO IT IS NOT**. Too many extensions. But I like it and use it a lot. Even switch ... case ranges!! (fanatics for sure are getting the stroke/heart attack now)

Comment: @P__J__ `-Wpedantic` / `-pedantic`.

Comment: @EOF it is a joke :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not the allocation. Silab Gecko is a ARM M-3 based uC. This uC is alignment sensitive and objects are placed by the linker this way to have addresses dividable by `4` to avoid alignment problems. It is defined in the linker script.

Comment: It's not immediately clear from your answer how alignment affects allocation, as `char[4]` and `char[5]` are both aligned in the same way. You should probably clarify that, even though "usable" memory of `char[5]` is still 5 bytes, the trailing 3 bytes have to be consumed too because nothing else can be put there (as it would become unaligned).

Comment: @GSerg You could *absolutely* use the memory, for either a single 16-bit `[unsigned] short` and a single 8-bit `[unsigned] char` or three `[unsigned] char`s.

Comment: @EOF Would those be exempt from the alignment requirements? And if so, this answer does not stand.

Comment: Understood about the alignment aspects. But if I understand the comments so far, a declaration of char X[3] would only consume 3 bytes (one 32 bit word though) and the compiler/linker will handle the byte masking/shifting to make a statement such as Y = X[2]  work. I understand that as a C statement it will work, the core question is about memory. So the compiler will help efficiently use RAM but I suspect the assembly code will take a small hit in size. No?

Comment: @BobK https://www.silabs.com/mcu/32-bit/efm32-leopard-gecko suggest that the underlying processor is an ARM cortexm3, which has native byte and short load/store instructions. No shifting/masking is required.

Comment: @BobK byte accesses are always aligned :) http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABFAIGG.html

Comment: @GSerg See my comment to Bobk, and try reading the documentation a bit (ARM architecture reference manual, in this case).

Comment: @EOF and @ P__J__: Got it! I overlooked those particular notes. Thanks to everyone for your help!